# How to remove NSDate objects from a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have been working with `NSArray`s and `NSMutableArray`s that store `NSDate` objects for a few days now. I noticed that calling `[listOfDates removeObject:date1]` removes all the `NSDate` objects from the array. I have instead been doing this to remove objects:

```
  NSMutableArray *dateList; // Has Dates in it
  NSDate *dateToRemove;     // Date Object to Remove
  __block NSUInteger indexToRemove;
  __block BOOL       foundMatch = NO;
  [dateList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToDate:dateToRemove]) {
      indexToRemove = idx;
      foundMatch = YES;
      *stop = YES;
     }
  }];
  if (foundMatch) {
    [dateList removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
  }
```

Is there a better way to be doing this? Perhaps another data structure? Or a simpler function?

Comment: If you have the actual object from the array (vs a copy), use `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`.  Otherwise, `removeObjectAtIndex:`.

Comment: I have read it, It states `Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message`. I think my problem is the NSDate objects isEqual implementation doesn't look at the date time stored in the object. So I am wondering if there are some other solutions people have used.

Comment: Your problem is that NSDate objects DO implement isEqual, and you have multiple equal NSDate objects in the array.

Comment: I found that problem, Michael was correct. removeObject: does work. I must have had the wrong objects in my array. I tested removeObject: and it worked as expected/hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the first method you tried:

```
[listOfDates removeObject:date1];
```

This will remove date1 and ONLY date1 from `listOfDates`. This should NOT remove all NSDate objects from `listOfDates` unless all NSDate objects in `listOfDates` are `date1`.

You could also use removeObjectAtIndex: combined with indexOfObject: to product the same effect, but that's extra code.

From the [NSMutableArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `removeObject`:

> This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes
>   them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined on
>   the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message. If the
>   array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it
>   does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

Answer (score 0):

If all the dates in dateList are equal, `removeObject` will not remove only one, but all of them. To remove only one, a shorter version is to get the first index, and then to remove the object at that index:

```
NSUInteger indexToRemove = [dateList indexOfObject:dateToRemove];
if (indexToRemove != NSNotFound) {
    [dateList removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
}
```